# Favorite way to create an new IEnumerable<T> sequence from a single value?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I usually create a sequence from a single value using array syntax, like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> sequence = new string[] { "abc" };
```

Or using a new List. I'd like to hear if anyone has a more expressive way to do the same thing.

Comment: How is that an empty sequence?

Comment: It's just embarrassing that dotnet still doesn't have something like `Enumerable.From<T>(params T[] items)`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Your example is not an empty sequence, it's a sequence with one element.  To create an empty sequence of strings you can do

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

**EDIT** OP clarified they were looking to create a single value.  In that case

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Repeat("abc",1);
```

Comment: D'oh, I got distracted, sorry. I meant create from an single value, not create an empty instance!

Comment: This is 'the answer' flag it?

Comment: This method is more purely functional than creating a new array.

Answer (score 78):

I like what you suggest, but with the array type omitted:

```
var sequence = new[] { "abc" };
```

Comment: I never realized that you could do that. I think this is clearer than using Repeat.

Comment: But this isn't an IEnumerable, it's an array!

Comment: @Bryan Watts I know that, but it's a concrete implementation of an IEnumerable.  The question is asking for an IEnumerable<> (even if the example isn't).  There's a difference.

Comment: Maybe the question should be changed.

Comment: the reason i researched this was trying to mock a method that returns `Task<IEnumerable<>>`.  So this doesn't help.

Comment: @Jonesopolis: That is a different, unrelated situation. You can use `Task.FromResult` to achieve that.

Comment: @Jonesopolis, If you are in a situation where you want the type to be strictly `IEnumerable<string>` (and not just some specific type that implements it), then it may help to do `new[] { "abc" }.AsEnumerable()` instead. An example could be `Task.FromResult(new[] { "abc" }.AsEnumerable())` where the type argument to the `FromResult<>` method is _inferred_. This is shorter than `Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<string>>(new[] { "abc" })` (and when the type name is more complex than just `string`, it will be even more economical).

Answer (score 25):

Or even shorter,

```
string[] single = { "abc" };
```

I would make an extension method:

```
public static T[] Yield<T>(this T item)
{
    T[] single = { item };
    return single;
}
```

Or even better and shorter, just

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
{
    yield return item;
}
```

Perhaps this is exactly what `Enumerable.Repeat` is doing under the hood.

Comment: The last one is brilliant.  Except for the name... it will conflict with types that already implement IEnumerable such as the string in your example.  Try .AsSingleItemEnumerable(), or simply .Yield() -->  "abc".Yield()

Comment: I think ToEnumerable is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 `Yield` is good. I made `IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T source, params T[] others)` too.

Comment: I tried to do away with Yield altogether in favour of a lambda but somehow it never compiled... cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217729/in-c-why-cant-an-anonymous-method-contain-a-yield-statement ;-).

Comment: @PeterSchneider how and why did you do that? Without seeing code I cannot comment. I dont think I follow you.

Comment: Well, I simply played around, today, for no good reason. I wanted to pass e.g.  `(item) => yield return item;` to a function which expects an IEnumerable, or define a Func<IEnumerable<item>> = () => yield return 1;` or such. But it's impossible to do that for the reasons mentioned in the accepted answer of the question I pointed to.

Comment: @PeterSchneider that's right. I got you now. C# doesn't let you do that. Instead, if you have the above Yield method as in the answer you could pass `1.Yield()` to the function. Or to define anonymous function, you do: `Func<IEnumerable<int>> = () => 1.Yield();`

Answer (score 8):

or just create a method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
{
    if(items == null)
        yield break;

    foreach (T mitem in items)
        yield return mitem;
}
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
{
   return items ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

usage :

```
IEnumerable<string> items = CreateEnumerable("single");
```