# Why i can't use yield return on lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, yield-return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, why can't an anonymous method contain a yield statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217729/in-c-why-cant-an-anonymous-method-contain-a-yield-statement)

I have this code:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>> allNumbers = ()=> new []{1,2,3};
foreach (var number in allNumbers())
  Console.WriteLine(number);
```

But i would like (and has sense) to do somthing like this:

```
int i = 0;
Func<IEnumerable<int>> allNumbers = () => {yield return ++i;};
foreach (var number in allNumbers())
   Console.WriteLine(number);
```

and i get this compile error:
"The yield statement cannot be used inside an anonymous method or lambda expression"

So why i can't use yield returns (lazy things) inside c# lambda expressions?