# yield return in the lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq

The follow code will break the list into sub-lists which begins with "[" and end with "]". How to convert it to use `yield return` so it can handle very huge stream input lazily? --Or how to implement it in F# with lazily enumerating?-- (never mind, I think f#implementation should be trivial)

```
var list = new List<string> { "[", "1", "2", "3", "]", "[", "2", "2", "]", "[", "3", "]" };
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result = Split(list);

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Split(List<string> list)
{
    return list.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(), // yield return?
    (sum, current) =>
    {
        if (current == "[")
            sum.Add(new List<string>());
        else if (current == "]")
            return sum; // Convert to yield return?
        else
            sum.Last().Add(current);
        return sum; // Convert to yield return?
    });
}
```

Comment: Feels like aggregate is not quite the right thing to use here. Write your own version of it, then superimpose the logic on top.

Comment: @leppie The problem with the `Aggregate` is that he's not actually aggregating anything.  The lambda is only ever used for its side effects, so it's noting more than a much harder to read `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C# doesn't support anonymous iterator blocks, so you'll simply need to use a named method instead of an anonymous method.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Split(IEnumerable<string> tokens)
{
    using(var iterator = tokens.GetEnumerator())
        while(iterator.MoveNext())
            if(iterator.Current == "[")
                yield return SplitGroup(iterator);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> SplitGroup(
    IEnumerator<string> iterator)
{
    while(iterator.MoveNext() && iterator.Current != "]")
        yield return iterator.Current;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217729/in-c-why-cant-an-anonymous-method-contain-a-yield-statement

Answer (score 1):

While C# not allow `yield` in lambda I think we could workaround like this

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Split(List<string> list)
{
    var tmp = list as IEnumerable<string>;
    while(tmp.FirstOrDefault() == "[")
    {
        yield return tmp.TakeWhile((current) => current != "]");
        tmp = tmp.SkipWhile((current) => current != "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I found another way of doing this, using `Linq`.  Not sure on efficience, but it works.

```
int index=0;
list.Select(item=> new { item=item, index= item=="]"? ++index : index })
                  .Where(c => !(c.item == "[" || c.item =="]"))
                  .GroupBy(g=>g.index)
                  .Select(e=> e.Select(c=>c.item));
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PXznWy)

Comment: That's not lazily generating the sequence.  `Groupby` is going to need to process the *entire* sequence before it can yield any results, which the OP has said they don't want to do.