# foreach vs ForEach using yield

Tags: c#, yield

Is it possible to use `yield` inline at the `ForEach` method?

```
private static IEnumerable<string> DoStuff(string Input)
{
    List<string> sResult = GetData(Input);
    sResult.ForEach(x => DoStuff(x));

    //does not work
    sResult.ForEach(item => yield return item;); 

    //does work
    foreach(string item in sResult) yield return item;
}
```

if not, is there a reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1217729/1859022

Comment: First, *Why* use this syntax instead of `.Select(x=>DoStuff(x))` ? Second, `ForEach` doesn't return a result, so trying to return something with `return` or `yield` is invalid

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Select` doesn't work combined with a recursive approach

Comment: @fubo actually, you can find ways to make it work. You'll find many examples that show how eg to walk trees with LINQ. At the very least you can use `.Concat` to combine recursion results befor returning the result from select. Trying to use a `yield` inside an Action is simply invalid though.

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is something like `foreach(var item in GetData(Input)) { foreach(var sub in DoStuff(item)){ yield return sub; } yield return item;}`  Or you might want to yield the `item` before the `sub` items.

Comment: Without even going into deep detail which answered here already, you're trying to compare `ForEach` method vs `foreach` flow control keyword. And as it is pointed above you can't return anything from `ForEach`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because as you can see [here](http://goo.gl/Vr6xCZ) a lambda function is compiled to a separate method:

This:

```
x => DoStuff(x)
```

is converted to

```
internal void <DoStuff>b__1_0(string x)
{
    C.DoStuff(x);
}
```

This separate method isn't a `IEnumerable<>` so it clearly can't support the `yield` keyword.

So for example this:

```
item => yield return item;
```

would be converted to:

```
internal void <DoStuff>b__1_0(string item)
{
    yield return item;
}
```

that has the `yield` but isn't `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 9):

No, [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) can't be used for this.

`List<T>.ForEach` takes an [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate.

`Action<T>` "Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value."

So the lambda you've created can't return anything if it's to "fit" in an `Action<T>`.