# Understanding .AsEnumerable() in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asenumerable

Given the following LINQ to SQL query:

```
var test = from i in Imports
           where i.IsActive
           select i;
```

The interpreted SQL statement is:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [Id] .... FROM [Imports] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[isActive] = 1
```

Say I wanted to perform some action in the select that cannot be converted to SQL. Its my understanding that the conventional way to accomplish this is to do `AsEnumerable()` thus converting it to a workable object.

Given this updated code:

```
var test = from i in Imports.AsEnumerable()
           where i.IsActive
           select new 
           { 
               // Make some method call 
           };
```

And updated SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [Id] ... FROM [Imports] AS [t0]
```

Notice the lack of a where clause in the executed SQL statement.

Does this mean the entire "Imports" table is cached into memory? 
Would this slow performance at all if the table contained a large amount of records?

Help me to understand what is actually happening behind the scenes here.

Comment: Have a look at examples from another question:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129116/1792434

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The reason for [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is to

> AsEnumerable(TSource)(IEnumerable(TSource))
>   can be used to choose between query
>   implementations when a sequence
>   implements IEnumerable(T) but also has
>   a different set of public query
>   methods available

So when you were calling the `Where` method before, you were calling a different `Where` method from the `IEnumerable.Where`. That `Where` statement was for LINQ to convert to SQL, the new `Where` is the `IEnumerable` one that takes an `IEnumerable`, enumerates it and yields the matching items. Which explains why you see the different SQL being generated. The table will be taken in full from the database before the `Where` extension will be applied in your second version of the code. This could create a serious bottle neck, because the entire table has to be in memory, or worse the entire table would have to travel between servers. Allow SQL server to execute the `Where` and do what it does best.

Comment: So it still has deferred execution right? Using the above query as an example, the entire "Imports" table wont be stored in memory just the active ones, when I do something like "test.Dump()". 

Is that correct?

Comment: @Mike Fielden Well the entire table will go through memory as the Where is enumerating it. I'm not sure if all rows will be loaded into memory at the same time.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: So why does it exist? Kindly tell the pros too of using AsEnumerable. Thanks

Comment: @Unbreakable for example when you want to apply a filter (e.g. some complicated lambda expression) that the query implementation doesn't support. You could first apply a `Where` method with some initial filtering, then call `AsEnumerable` and then another `Where` which refines the filter criteria (using the lambda not supported by the query). This way you overcome query implementation limitations, while still being able to pre-filter the query so that you don't fetch all the data.

Comment: I've just realized that this is basically what Jon Hanna described in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

At the point where the enumeration is enumerated through, the database will then be queried, and the entire resultset retrieved.

A part-and-part solution can be the way. Consider

```
var res = (
    from result in SomeSource
    where DatabaseConvertableCriterion(result)
    && NonDatabaseConvertableCriterion(result)
    select new {result.A, result.B}
);
```

Let's say also that NonDatabaseConvertableCriterion requires field C from result. Because NonDatabaseConvertableCriterion does what its name suggests, this has to be performed as an enumeration. However, consider:

```
var partWay =
(
    from result in SomeSource
    where DatabaseConvertableCriterion(result)
    select new {result.A, result.B, result.C}
);
var res =
(
    from result in partWay.AsEnumerable()
    where NonDatabaseConvertableCriterion select new {result.A, result.B}
);
```

In this case, when res is enumerated, queried or otherwise used, as much work as possible will be passed to the database, which will return enough to continue the job. Assuming that it is indeed really impossible to rewrite so that all the work can be sent to the database, this may be a suitable compromise.

Answer (score 6):

There are three implementations of `AsEnumerable`.

**[`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Extends a `DataTable` to give it an `IEnumerable` interface so you can use Linq against the `DataTable`.

**[`Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`ParallelEnumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

> The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect
>   other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that
>   implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself.
>
> `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` can be used to choose
>   between query implementations when a sequence implements
>   `IEnumerable<T>` but also has a different set of public query methods
>   available. For example, given a generic class `Table` that implements
>   `IEnumerable<T>` and has its own methods such as `Where`, `Select`, and
>   `SelectMany`, a call to `Where` would invoke the public `Where` method of
>   `Table`. A `Table` type that represents a database table could have a
>   `Where` method that takes the predicate argument as an expression tree
>   and converts the tree to SQL for remote execution. If remote execution
>   is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local
>   method, the `AsEnumerable<TSource>` method can be used to hide the
>   custom methods and instead make the standard query operators
>   available.

**In other words.**

If I have an

```
IQueryable<X> sequence = ...;
```

from a LinqProvider, like Entity Framework, and I do,

```
sequence.Where(x => SomeUnusualPredicate(x));
```

that query will be composed and run on the server. This will fail at runtime because the EntityFramework doesn't know how to convert `SomeUnusualPredicate` into SQL.

If I want that to run the statement with Linq to Objects instead,  I do,

```
sequence.AsEnumerable().Where(x => SomeUnusualPredicate(x));
```

now the server will return all the data and the `Enumerable.Where` from Linq to Objects will be used instead of the Query Provider's implementation.

It won't matter that Entity Framework doesn't know how to interpret `SomeUnusualPredicate`,  my function will be used directly. (However, this may be an inefficient approach since all rows will be returned from the server.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the AsEnumerable just tells the compiler which extension methods to use (in this case the ones defined for IEnumerable instead of those for IQueryable).
The execution of the query is still deferred until you call ToArray or enumerate on it.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. AsEnumerable is a method. It doesn't "tell the compiler" anything in particular.

Comment: Yes it is a method, but it's return type is Enumerable hence the compiler will use different methods when compiling the LINQ query (the Enumerable ones). From the documentation: The AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx

Comment: I agree with @Razvi, AsEnumerable() defers the execution of the query until you call any Linq method that returns a dataset.