# Get Last Record from Multiple Records and save result in LINQ List

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I have a table 'Status`Which has multiple status of`User`. I just want to read the last`Status`of every`user`. How could I achive that in Lambda Linq to SQL.

```
-------Status-------------
|   user1, Stats_Active   |
|   user1, Stats_InActive |
|   user1, Stats_Deleted  |
|   user2, Stats_Login    |
|   user2, Stats_Logout   |
|   user2, Stats_Edited   |
________________________
```

I want to get the following output:

```
User1, Status_Delete
User2,Status_edited
```

This is my Linq to SQL Query:

```
EntityName db = new EntityName();
var result = db.Status.OrderByDescending(k=> k.DateTime).List()
```

This just returns the whole list in Descending order. How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
var result = db.Status
               .AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(s=>s.UserId)
               .Select(gr=>
               {
                   // Generally you should avoid use the First
                   // and you should use the FirstOrDefault
                   // but in this context is safe to use First.
                   var mostRecentComplaint = gr.OrderByDescending(k=> k.DateTime)
                                               .First();
                   return new Complaint_DTO
                   {
                       ComplaintId = gr.Key,
                       Status = mostRecentComplaint.Status,
                       CreatedDate = mostRecentComplaint.CreatedDate
                   };
               }).ToList();
```

- First we group by our items by the UserId. So all the records that have the same UserId goes to the same group.
- Then Ordering the result of each group by descending DateTime and getting the first item of each of these groups, we get the expected result.

Comment: It gives me error when I try to use the List of my Class
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Guid,DTO.User_DTO>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DTO.User_DTO>`

Comment: Then you have in the Select clause use the User_DTO class. I will update my post and if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: I did use the `User_DTO` class, but the problem is when I use `var` it works fine, but if I use `List<User_DTO>` it gives me this error

Comment: If you use the `User_DTO`, then the result of the query it would a `List<User_DTO>`. I can't get what you mean by saying if I yse `List<User_DTO>`. Where do you want to use this?

Comment: Somehow, the result of above query returns a List of `IGrouping` how can I cast this result into my List of User_DTO ?

Comment: Did you make the mentioned change, `.Select(gr=>new User_DTO{...}` and it still returns a List of `IGrouping`? A sequence of `IGrouping` is returned by the `GroupBy`. Then using the `Select` you create another sequence, a sequence of `User_DTO` objects and last but not least calling the `ToList` at the end you create a `List<User_DTO>` based on this sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98590/discussion-between-programer-and-christos).

Comment: But why do you need to call `AsEnumerable`?

Comment: Because calling the `AsEnumerable` you will fetch the data in memory and you would do there the grouping and the further processing, using linq to entities. This is needed, because we can't  a use lambda expression with a statement body, in LINQ to SQL. Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311244/understanding-asenumerable-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Thanks for the info @Christos, so right know I have my doubts if my queries work or not, because I think the `let` expression is included inside the `select` expression, but I don't remember having troubles with something like that in the past. When I have time I'm going to test it.

Comment: @octavioccl You are welcome ! You shouldn't have any doubt. If I was to write the linq query using the query syntax, I would have picked certainly the let keyword. I just wanted to write this query using the fluent syntax using method calls. By the way, all the queries we write in query sytax during the compilation are transformed to method calls, since CLR is not aware of query syntax. If you would like, I would suggest you read this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/linq-fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other.

Comment: Thanks again @Christos, I tested my first query and it works on the server side. I didn't have to call `AsEnumerable` to execute the query using Linq to Objects, it works well using Linq to Entities. I'm going to update my answer to show the results.

Comment: As you can see in my answer to avoid  execute all your query in memory you can do two `Select` to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `UserId` and then order your groups by `DateTime` property:

```
var result =(from s in db.Status
             group s by s.UserId into g
             let first=g.OrderByDescending(s=>s.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()
             select new { userId= g.Key, Status= first.Status, CreatedDate=first.CreatedDate}).ToList();
```

### Update

I tested my query using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), and it was translated to this lambda expression:

```
Status
   .GroupBy (a => a.UserId)
   .Select (
      g => 
         new  
         {
            g = g, 
            first = g.OrderBy (a => a.DateTime).FirstOrDefault ()
         }
   )
   .Select (
      temp0 => 
         new  
         {
            Key = temp0.g.Key, 
            Status= temp0.first.Status,
            CreatedDate=temp0.first.CreatedDate
         }
   )
```

Which is translated at the end to this SQL query:

```
SELECT [t1].[UserId] AS [UserId], (
    SELECT [t3].[Status], [t3].[DateTime]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[Status]
        FROM [Status] AS [t2]
        WHERE (([t1].[UserId] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[UserId] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[UserId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[UserId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[UserId] = [t2].[UserId]))
        ORDER BY [t2].[DateTime]
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [Status],(
    SELECT [t5].[DateTime]
    FROM (
      SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[DateTime]
      FROM [Application] AS [t4]
      WHERE (([t1].[UserId] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[UserId] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[UserId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[UserId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[UserId] = [t4].[UserId]))
      ORDER BY [t4].[DateTime]
      ) AS [t5]
    ) AS [DateTime]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[UserId]
    FROM [Application] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[UserId]
    ) AS [t1]
```

Comment: If there's no datetime column, you can follow this pattern to order by descending ID if you have one (assuming an autonumbered identity column)

Comment: What if I don't want to use `var` ?

Comment: Well, you'll need to create a custom class to save your result. I recommend you to search in internet what is a DTO.