# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities. (ASP.NET Web API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI controller to generate xml from table data

here is code

```
  public class XMLController : ApiController
{
    private trackingappEntities db = new trackingappEntities();
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index()
    {
        var xdoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("data",
                db.TimeTables.Select(w =>
                    new XElement("worker",
                        new XAttribute("id", w.INN),
                        new XElement("start", w.StartDay),
                        new XElement("pause", w.StartPause),
                        new XElement("continue", w.EndPause),
                        new XElement("end", w.EndDay)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(xdoc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") };
    }
}
```

Here is TimeTable class

```
 public partial class TimeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string INN { get; set; }
    public string StartDay { get; set; }
    public string StartPause { get; set; }
    public string EndDay { get; set; }
    public string EndPause { get; set; }
}
```

But when I send request, I have this response

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

How I can fix this?

Comment: One of your entities has a constuctor with a parameter in it, and you didn't create an empty constructor for it

Comment: `XElement` & `XAttribute` methods are not intended to use with LINQ to Entities (they're work with LINQ to Objects). Try to materialize the `IQueryable` first (using `AsEnumerable` or `ToList`).

Comment: So i need to `new XDocument` To List first? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: @mark_spencer `db.TimeTables.AsEnumerable().Select(...)` or `db.TimeTables.ToList().Select(...)` can be enough to materalize query results into memory (those XML methods obviously have no SQL equivalent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ works by inspecting the *code* of your function calls, rather than simply their result.

In your case, the likely solution will just be to call [`AsEnumerable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311342/1270504) to tell LINQ to populate each record from SQL, before calling the constructor.

```
var timeTables = db.TimeTables
    /*
     * Select is optional; this would improve performance for a table with many 
     * extra properties, but would have little-to-no relevant impacts if you're
     * already using them all. Similar to a SELECT * versus selecting individual
     * columns.
     */
    .Select(c => new {
        c.INN,
        c.StartDay,
        c.StartPause,
        c.EndPause,
        c.EndDay
    })
    .AsEnumerable(); // or ...await ToListAsync();

var xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("data",
            timeTables.Select(w =>
                new XElement("worker",
                    new XAttribute("id", w.INN),
                    new XElement("start", w.StartDay),
                    new XElement("pause", w.StartPause),
                    new XElement("continue", w.EndPause),
                    new XElement("end", w.EndDay)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Otherwise, you can imagine LINQ trying to essentially send the logic for generating an `XElement` directly to SQL. Since SQL wouldn't understand the logic involved in that process, LINQ throws.

In this example, the `Select` call builds an anonymous type. Because it's guaranteed to have no additional logic performed in the constructor, LINQ is able to simply select those values, and populate them C#-side.