# Query AzureDB document for document with ID?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to query a 'course' document in the 'id' database I have, I've got the following:

```
collUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("id", "course");
            if(client.CreateDocumentQuery(collUrl).Where((x)=>x.Id == "course1").FirstOrDefault() == null){
```

Yields the error:

> [30/01/2018 6:26:19 AM] Exception while executing function:
>   SynchCourse. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred.
>   (Query expression is invalid, expression
>   https://mydb-australiaeast.documents.azure.com/dbs/id/colls/course.Where(x
>   => (x.Id == "course1")).FirstOrDefault() is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where', 'Queryable.Select' &
>   'Queryable.SelectMany', Windows/10.0.16299
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.7.1). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Query
>   expression is invalid, expression
>   https://mydb-australiaeast.documents.azure.com/dbs/id/colls/course.Where(x
>   => (x.Id == "course1")).FirstOrDefault() is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where', 'Queryable.Select' &
>   'Queryable.SelectMany', Windows/10.0.16299
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.7.1. [30/01/2018 6:26:19 AM] Exception while
>   executing function: SynchCourse [30/01/2018 6:26:19 AM] Exception
>   while executing function: SynchCourse. System.Private.CoreLib: One or
>   more errors occurred. (Query expression is invalid, expression
>   https://mydb-australiaeast.documents.azure.com/dbs/id/colls/course.Where(x
>   => (x.Id == "course1")).FirstOrDefault() is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where', 'Queryable.Select' &
>   'Queryable.SelectMany', Windows/10.0.16299
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.7.1). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Query
>   expression is invalid, expression
>   https://mydb-australiaeast.documents.azure.com/dbs/id/colls/course.Where(x
>   => (x.Id == "course1")).FirstOrDefault() is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where', 'Queryable.Select' &
>   'Queryable.SelectMany', Windows/10.0.16299
>   documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.7.1. [30/01/2018 6:26:19 AM] Function
>   completed (Failure, Id=d2f1ab38-32f2-46a3-9831-94477b113205,
>   Duration=37625ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try to use the following code.

```
if(client.CreateDocumentQuery(collUrl).Where((x)=>x.Id == "course1").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault() == null)
```

The reason for [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is to

> AsEnumerable(TSource)(IEnumerable(TSource)) can be used to choose between query implementations when a sequence implements IEnumerable(T) but also has a different set of public query methods available

For more information, you also could refer to [Understanding .AsEnumerable() in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311244/understanding-asenumerable-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: I get the error: (Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)). Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you mentioned on my side, but I find a smilar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/202) in the github. If possible please have a try to update the [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/1.19.1) version  to 1.19.1. If that is not helpful,  there is a reproduce demo project, it will be more helpful.