# How can I create a singleton IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

Does C# offer some nice method to cast a single entity of type `T` to `IEnumerable<T>`?

The only way I can think of is something like:

```
T entity = new T();
IEnumerable<T> = new List { entity }.AsEnumerable();
```

And I guess there should be a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779442/return-single-instance-object-as-ienumerable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a single item as IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577822/passing-a-single-item-as-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your call to `AsEnumerable()` is unnecessary. `AsEnumerable` is usually used in cases where the target object implements `IQueryable<T>` but you want to force it to use LINQ-to-Objects (when doing client-side filtering on a LINQ-compatible ORM, for example). Since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but not `IQueryable<T>`, there's no need for it.

Anyway, you could also create a single-element array with your item;

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerable = new[] { t };
```

Or `Enumerable.Repeat`

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerable = Enumerable.Repeat(t, 1);
```

Comment: Notes: the array constructor syntax is significantly more efficient (but such micro-optimization is often not relevant); the repeat method on the other hand is guaranteed to be immutable.

Comment: I like that Enumerable.Repeat allows you to hide the backing type. Also, I >assume< it's probably implemented with a loop/yield, and so can be the basis for a deferred execution implementation.

Comment: @Sprague: If by "hide the backing type", you're referring to the ability to call `Repeat` without explicitly specifying the generic arguments, then the implicit array syntax (`new[] { t }`) does the same thing.

Comment: @AdamRobinson No, perhaps a confusing choice of words on my part. I was referring to the implementation of IEnumerable (array v. list v. value-yielding function)

Answer (score 6):

I use

```
Enumerable.Repeat(entity, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var entity = new T();
var singleton = Enumerable.Repeat(entity, 1);
```

(Although I'd probably just do `var singleton = new[] { entity };` in most situations, especially if it was only for private use.)

Comment: Strangely VB.NET is less verbose than C#! Creating the array is just `{ entity }`.

Comment: @Martinho: In C# you can do `T[] x = { y }` or `var x = new[] { y }`, but not `var x = { y }`.