# How can I enumerable one item

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I create a singleton IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960091/how-can-i-create-a-singleton-ienumerable)
>   [Favorite way to create an new IEnumerable<T> sequence from a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019737/favorite-way-to-create-an-new-ienumerablet-sequence-from-a-single-value)

Say I need to return an IEnumerable which contains only one element.

I could return a list as in

```
return new List<Whatever> (myItem);
```

or an array for that matter.

But it would be preferable to create a Singleton method

```
public IEnumerable<T> Singleton (T t)
{
yield return t
}
```

Before I put this everywhere in my code, isn't there a method which already does this?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to enumerate a singleton?

Comment: Why would the singleton be preferable? It seems like something rarely needed, and when it should be ad-hoc, tailored to the flow.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019737/favorite-way-to-create-an-new-ienumerablet-sequence-from-a-single-value

Comment: When you use the term "singleton", people are going to think of the singleton pattern.  What you're doing here is not implementing the singleton pattern, it's emitting a sequence with a single item in it.

Answer (score 7):

The closest method available in the .NET framework is `Enumerable.Repeat(myItem,1)` but I would just use `new[]{myItem}`.

Comment: This is not as efficient as a singleton method

Comment: In fact it is _more_ efficient.

Comment: @user why do you think it is not as efficient as a singleton method?

Answer (score 2):

```
Enumerable.Repeat(t, 1);
```

That seems equivalent. Don't know anything better.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the item as the only item in an IEnumerable.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="this">The item.</param>
/// <returns>An IEnumerable containing only the item.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<TItem> AsEnumerable<TItem>(this TItem @this)
{
    return new [] { @this };
}
```

Comment: One of the few extension methods use-cases where you may not want to throw an exception on `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Passing a single item as IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577822/passing-a-single-item-as-ienumerablet)

You can wither pass a single item like

```
new T[] { item }
```

OR in C# 3.0 you can utilize the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1);
```