# Making a generic scheduler of Action<T> with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm experimenting a lot with Reactive Extensions and right now I'm trying to make a system in which I can queue procedures and execute them in whatever fashion I want while being able to send notifications to subscribers.

I currently have my database access encapsulated within a UserAccess class that exposes the method to add a user. In that method I would like to queue an action that adds a user to the database. So I made a JobProcessor of T class that exposes a method QueueJob(Action) and have my User implement this class. My problem is I can't see how to call the Action from within the OnNext method of the Observable because the action takes a User parameter.

My angle of attack must be wrong and there must be a problem with my grasp of the design. For example I know I should somehow pass my user to the QueueJob procedure but I don't know how to do it in a clean way.

```
    public class UserAccess : JobProcessor<User>
    {
        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            QueueJob(usr =>
                     {
                         using (var db = new CenterPlaceModelContainer())
                         {
                             db.Users.Add(usr);
                         }

                     });
         [...]

    public abstract class JobProcessor<T>
    {
        // Either Subject<T> or Subject<Action<T>>
        private Subject<Action<T>> JobSubject = new Subject<Action<T>>();

        public JobProcessor()
        {
            JobSubject
            /* Insert Rx Operators Here */
            .Subscribe(OnJobNext, OnJobError, OnJobComplete);
        }

        private void OnJobNext(Action<T> action)
        {
            // ???
        }

        private void OnJobError(Exception exception)
        {

        }

        private void OnJobComplete()
        {

        }

        public void QueueJob(Action<T> action)
        {
            JobSubject.OnNext(action);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1 :**

I tried to change the signature of QueueJob to

```
QueueJob(T entity, Action<T> action)
```

Now I can do

```
QueueJob(user, usr => { ... } );
```

But it does not seem very intuitive. I haven't seen many frameworks in which you pass both the entity and the action. With that I might as well not need the JobProcessor.

**Edit 2 :** 
I changed my JobProcessor's subject type to Subject, removing the T altogether. Since there was no need to include the User in the procedure since I can refer to it externally. The only problem now is if the User I pass to the QueueJob's action changes between the actual time of the Action execution, the user will have the modified information. Undesirable but I guess I will continue looking for a solution.

My code is now (used Buffer for sample) :

```
public abstract class JobProcessor
{
   public Subject<Action> JobSubject = new Subject<Action>();

   public JobProcessor()
   {
       JobSubject
           .Buffer(3)
           .Subscribe(OnJobNext, OnJobError, OnJobComplete);
   }

   private void OnJobNext(IList<Action> actionsList)
   {
       foreach (var element in actionsList)
        {
            element();
        }
   }

   private void OnJobError(Exception exception)
   {

   }

   private void OnJobComplete()
   {

   }

   public void QueueJob(Action action)
   {
       JobSubject.OnNext(action);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I have to agree with Lee and NSGaga that you *probably* don't want to do it this way - there are other patterns for a Producer/Consumer queue that are far more aligned with what (I think) you are trying to accomplish here.

That said, since I can never resist a challenge...with some minor tweaks, you can remove your immediate problem of "What do I pass into the action?" by just capturing the user parameter passed in and making it a straight-up `Action` - Here's your code with some modifications:

```
public class UserAccess : JobProcessor
{
    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        QueueJob(() =>
                 {
                     using (var db = new CenterPlaceModelContainer())
                     {
                         db.Users.Add(user);
                     }

                 });
     [...]

public abstract class JobProcessor
{
    // Subject<Action>
    private Subject<Action> JobSubject = new Subject<Action>();

    public JobProcessor()
    {
        JobSubject
        /* Insert Rx Operators Here */
        .Subscribe(OnJobNext, OnJobError, OnJobComplete);
    }

    private void OnJobNext(Action action)
    {
        // Log something saying "Yo, I'm executing an action" here?
        action();
    }

    private void OnJobError(Exception exception)
    {
        // Log something saying "Yo, something broke" here?
    }

    private void OnJobComplete()
    {
        // Log something saying "Yo, we shut down" here?
    }

    public void QueueJob(Action action)
    {
        JobSubject.OnNext(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the capture makes more sense (previous wasn't really working imo) - but it also raises more questions :). I'd rather queue users - then you get a list of users and do one Db sweep on that. And some other things. This is a good example / question though @Leroux - it'd be nice to have time for the challenge :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not frankly sure what is your `goal' here - but I think you got it backwards a bit...

Normally subject is exposed via property like
`IObservable<Action<T>> NewJob {get{return _subject;}}`
...or something. (Subject becomes observable - subject is dual in nature - and why it's specific - and a bit controversial - but good for playing around etc.)

And you just call `OnNext` from inside the class - like you did.

But you do not normally subscribe to the observable yourself
...you let the outside users do that by 'hooking' into your property - and defining subscribe - which gets them new items as they arrive.

This is simplified of course, there are many cases and many uses but this might help I hope

Comment: Indeed I think I might need some guidance, hence my question here. I want to have a queue of actions that I could process however I want. Might be one per second or simply accumulate actions for 10 seconds and them process just half of them, disregard the rest. I also want to be able to notify when an action is being processed and tell it to whoever subscribed. This is why I thought of a sequence that feeds the OnNext with the User information.

Comment: ...you're on a good track, just reorganize a bit - and I don't know ask some specific question then, it's too general for me. On the `Throttle` - you can use that to accumulate some more, or something similar (there're couple methods)

Comment: @Leroux I think I see what you mean now - I'll try to add an implementation later on

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction is that IObservable is normally best suited for creating sequences of immutable data structures, not method-pointers/delegates/actions.

Next I would suggest that if you are trying to 'schedule' actions to be processed in a queue fashion, then the IScheduler implementations in Rx seem like a perfect fit!

Alternatively if you are actually trying to create a ProduceConsumer Queue, then I dont think Rx is actually the best fit for this. i.e. if you are putting a heap of messages into a queue and then having some consumers reading these messages off and processing them, I would look to a different framework.

Comment: I would agree on not using Rx just for using Rx in a production environment but since I really like experimenting I thought that Rx was a fun idea for representing a sequence of execution that could be played at variable rate. Like batching up Create statements in a database. I was trying to go for a really generic class but I think I got lost in the process and the fun.

Comment: Cool. That is definitely the best way to learn Rx, by getting your hands dirty, trying some code, seeing what works and what doesn't. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I finalized my design and found something that I like. Here is the code if anyone else needs it.

```
public class JobProcessor<T> : IDisposable where T : new()
{
    private ISubject<Action<T>> jobsProcessor = new Subject<Action<T>>();

    private IDisposable disposer;

    private T _jobProvider = new T();

    public JobProcessor(Func<ISubject<Action<T>>, IObservable<IEnumerable<Action<T>>>> initializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering JobProcessor Constructor");

        disposer = initializer(jobsProcessor)
            .Subscribe(OnJobsNext, OnJobsError, OnJobsComplete);

        Console.WriteLine("Leaving JobProcessor Constructor");
    }

    private void OnJobsNext(IEnumerable<Action<T>> actions)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entering OnJobsNext");

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            action(_jobProvider);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving OnJobsNext");
    }

    private void OnJobsError(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entering OnJobsError");

        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving OnJobsError");
    }

    private void OnJobsComplete()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entering OnJobsComplete");

        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving OnJobsComplete");
    }

    public void QueueJob(Action<T> action)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entering QueueJobs");

        jobsProcessor.OnNext(action);

        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving QueueJobs");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I selected a generic make to support an architecture in layers where I could use the JobProcessor in a layer of concurrency where I could select how fast or slow my execution can be. The JobProcessor constructor takes a Func used to declare the Observable sequence somewhere else in the code and generate a processor that executes jobs an the order described by the sequence. The OnNext takes in an IEnumerable> to be able to support sequences like .Buffer(3) that returns a batch of actions at the same time. The downside to that is that when creating a sequence returning single actions at a time I need to do this

```
var x = new JobProcessor<DatabaseAccess<User>>(subject => subject.Select(action => action.Yield()));
```

The Yield() extension methof of T returns an enumerable of a single element. I found it here [Passing a single item as IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577822/passing-a-single-item-as-ienumerablet).