# Creating different URLs using specified parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, string-formatting

I have an MVC application and I am stuck at a point where I need some help with the logic on how should I proceed.

I have a variable named URL where in I am putting URLs. These URLs contains parameters and they look as follows:-

```
http://example.com/{Parameter1}/{Parameter2}
```

Now **{Parameter1}** has 4 values **a, b, c, d** and **{Parameter2}** has 3 values **1, 2, 3**.

Now using the values of these parameters I would get **12 URL** combinations. I want to display all 12 combinations with the help of C#.

How can create the algorithm with the code to display the combinations?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fairly trivial using `foreach` loops for every parameter:

```
var parameters1 = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var parameters2 = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };

foreach (var par1 in parameters1)
{
    foreach (var par2 in parameters2)
    {
        string url = string.Format("http://example.com/{0}/{1}", par1, par2);
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }
}
```

You may want to [put in a little recursion there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914299/recursion-in-place-of-multiple-nested-for-loops) if the parameter count varies.