# How to set a collection of objects onto a row, one object per cell?

Tags: c#, epplus

With EPPlus, given a collection of objects, how do I set the objects on a row, one object per cell?

That is, given:

```
int rowNumber = ...
int columnNumber = ...
IEnumerable<object> values = ...
```

How to set the values on the row `rowNumber`, starting on the column `columnNumber`, one value per cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LoadFromArrays` method on a range. The first cell where the arrays values should be set on the row is used to create the range.

The argument passed to `LoadFromArrays` is an `IEnumerable` of object arrays, so the `values` to set on the row should be first converted to an `object[]` and then wrapped as an `IEnumerable`

```
int rowNumber = ...
int columnNumber = ...
IEnumerable<object> values = ...

var range = ws.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber];
range.LoadFromArrays(AsEnumerable(values.ToArray())); 

/* ... */

// see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1577822/614800 for a discussion on how
// to wrap an object into an IEnumerable
private static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}
```