# GridView, It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

This is my Source Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gveducationInfo" CssClass="footable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Style="max-width: 600px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" DataKeyNames="Education_ID" OnRowCommand="gveducationInfo_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Education_ID" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddenColumn" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddenColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Degree_Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Year_Of_Passing" HeaderText="Year Of Passing" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Institute_Name" HeaderText="Institute Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State_ID" HeaderText="State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City_ID" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" />--%>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/images/edit16.png" CommandName="EditRow" ItemStyle-CssClass="align-center" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/images/delete16.png" CommandName="DeleteRow" ItemStyle-CssClass="align-center" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my C# coding

```
protected void butSave_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Business.ATS.ATS ats = new Business.ATS.ATS();
    Data.Education_Info education_Info = new Data.Education_Info();
    var state = ats.GetStates();
    var city = ats.GetCities();
    education_Info = ats.GetEducationInfo(Applicant_ID).SingleOrDefault();
    education_Info = new Data.Education_Info();
    education_Info.Education_ID = 0;
    education_Info.Applicant_ID = Applicant_ID;
    education_Info.Name = txtdegreename.Value;
    education_Info.Year_Of_Passing = txtyearofpassing.Value;
    education_Info.Institute_Name = txtnameofinstitution.Value;
    education_Info.City_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlcity.SelectedValue);
    education_Info.State_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlstate.SelectedValue);
    education_Info.Degree_Type = Convert.ToInt32(ddldegreetype.SelectedValue);
    ats.SaveEducationalInfo(education_Info);
    gveducationInfo.DataSource = ats.GetEduInfo().Last();
    gveducationInfo.DataBind();
}
```

this is my entity framwork db code

```
public IList<Education_Info> GetEduInfo()
{
    using (Data.ATSEntities dc = new Data.ATSEntities())
    {
        var lsteducationinfo = dc.Education_Info.ToList();
        return lsteducationinfo;
    }
}
```

when i fill the details in the web page and click save page i need to get last record entered by the user in gridview,  bu t igot the error

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource,
>   IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Anyone Know how to get ride of it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `Last()` here is the problem:

```
gveducationInfo.DataSource = ats.GetEduInfo().Last();
```

Delete the call to `Last()` like this:

```
gveducationInfo.DataSource = ats.GetEduInfo();
```

Why?

The `GetEduInfo` method returns an `IList`, and an `IList` implements `IEnumerable`, which will work with the `DataSource`. When you called `Last()`, though, you were no longer passing an `IEnumerable` but were instead passing the last item of the sequence, which won't work.

If you want to bind a single item to your `DataSource`, then you will need to wrap it up as an `IEnumerable`. You can use any of the answers to this [Passing a single item as IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1577822/1108891), such as wrapping the single item in an array:

```
gveducationInfo.DataSource = new Education_Info[] {ats.GetEduInfo().Last()};
```

Comment: i removed the Last()  but i got the full table in grid in webpage, but i need only last record that user enterted.  is that possible?? @Shaun Luttin

Comment: @KarthikeyanMuthukumaran Yes. That is possible. See edits.

Comment: Thank You so Much @Shaun Luttin