# Is there a neater linq way to 'Union' a single item?

Tags: c#, linq, union

If I have two sequences and I want to process them both together, I can union them and away we go.

Now lets say I have a single item I want to process between the two sequencs. I can get it in by creating an array with a single item, but is there a neater way? i.e.

```
var top = new string[] { "Crusty bread", "Mayonnaise" };
string filling = "BTL";
var bottom = new string[] { "Mayonnaise", "Crusty bread" };

// Will not compile, filling is a string, therefore is not Enumerable
//var sandwich = top.Union(filling).Union(bottom);

// Compiles and works, but feels grungy (looks like it might be smelly)
var sandwich = top.Union(new string[]{filling}).Union(bottom);

foreach (var item in sandwich)
    Process(item);
```

Is there an *approved* way of doing this, or is this the approved way?

Thanks

Comment: This is how I tend to do it.. doesn't feel happy but never figured it was worth working around.. Wonder if there's a way to write an implicit conversion between T and T array..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Favorite way to create an new IEnumerable<T> sequence from a single value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019737/favorite-way-to-create-an-new-ienumerablet-sequence-from-a-single-value)

Comment: You can simplify the union expression just a tad by reducing new string[] to just new[]. Otherwise, Jon Hanna's solution is probably the best way to go about this if you end up doing this sort of thing often.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One option is to overload it yourself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    return source.Union(Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1));
}
```

That's what we did with [`Concat`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Concat.cs) in [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/).

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat, perfect, thanks. I might indeed use that overload, thanks.

Comment: For extra nerdiness, name the overload `cons` :D

Comment: Every so often, when writing C# code, I do find myself longing for the set operation operators from languages like F# or LISP. Syntax like `list :: item` or `list1 @ list2` tend to be quite readable, once you're used to them.

Answer (score 12):

The new way of doing this, supported in .NET Core and .NET Framework from version 4.7.1, is using the [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method.

This will make your code as easy and elegant as

```
var sandwich = top.Append(filling).Union(bottom);
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using even more flexible approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return source.Union((IEnumerable<T>)items);
}
```

Works for single as well as multiple items.
You may also accept null `source` values:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return source != null ? source.Union((IEnumerable<T>)items) : items;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tend to have the following somewhere in my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmitFromEnum<T>(this T item)
{
  yield return item;
}
```

While it's not as neat to call `col.Union(obj.EmitFromEnum());` as `col.Union(obj)` it does mean that this single extension method covers all other cases I might want such a single-item enumeration.

Update: With .NET Core you can now use `.Append()` or `.Prepend()` to add a single element to an enumerable. The implementation is optimised to avoid generating too many `IEnumerator` implementations behind the scenes.

Comment: `public static IEnumerable<T> EmitFromEnum<T>(this T item)
{
    yield return item;
}`

Comment: @KuganKumar Yup. Thanks.