# Concatenate enumerable and a number in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best wayto add single element to an IEnumerable collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189563/what-is-the-best-wayto-add-single-element-to-an-ienumerable-collection)

Let's say I want to concantenate Enumerable.Repeat(100, 100) and the number 3, what is the nicest way to do this?

Of course I can do
`Enumerable.Repeat(100, 100).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(3,1))`, but it doesn't look very expressive...

Comment: "but it doesn't look very expressive"... k; what would your *ideal* syntax look like?

Comment: You can use ToList and then Add

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4189563/944681)

Comment: @MarcGravell: I think it would be like `numbers.Concat(3)`. An extension method does it. Anyway, I don't like doing things *too linq*.

Comment: @DannyChen what's wrong with numbers.Concat(3)?

Comment: @LouisRhys: It works, but what's wrong with `numbers.Concat(new[] { 3 })`? Creating a method to avoid the `new[] { }` syntax, is it worthy?

Comment: @DannyChen IMO new[] { } obscures the meaning for people reading the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    //the code here is not very expressive to you :)
}
```

**EDIT** It's suggested not to use the method name `Concat`, using `ConcatSingle` or `ConcatOne` instead, see the discussions in below comments.

Comment: The problem with this extension method is that it can break existing code. Consider the case where the item implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I don't think so. You can easily tell if `T item` is a *single* object or a collection in this method.

Comment: `class X : IEnumerable<X>{...}` => boom. While that's not the best design, introducing breaking changes with an extension method is simply unacceptable IMO. There is a reason the standard collections have both `Add` and `AddRange` instead of overloading `Add`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Ok..I admit what you said makes sense...because I can hardly imagine the usage scenario of `class X : IEnumerable<X>`..

Comment: You can use `class TreeNode:IEnumerable<TreeNode>` to express a tree. I nowadays prefer having a `Children` property, but I think I used it in some of my earlier projects.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Good example. I remember I used such a structure to store a tree data in the past, and like you I'd prefer a child property now.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm sure renaming the method to `ConcatSingle` or similar will help?

Comment: @LouisRhys Yes, naming it `ConcatSingle` is what I recommend, just like wizzardmr42's answer suggests. It's a useful method with a clear name and avoids overloading ambiguities.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to make it neat then the best thing to do would be to create an extension method for something like `ConcatSingle` and then call it.

Comment: +1 for using a different name from `Concat`. Reusing `Concat` can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an intermediate array which contains only that element:

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100).Concat(new []{ 3 });
```

You could also create an extension method to allow that without creating an  additional array:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}
```

Now this is possible:

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100).Concat(3.ToEnumerable());
```

Comment: I don't like the name of your extension method. Too close to `AsEnumerable` which does something completely different.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Renamed to `ToEnumerable` if that's better.

Comment: That's better, but I'm still not a fan. You don't convert the item to a sequence, you create a sequence that *contains* the item. So I still think that the name doesn't really fit its semantics.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: What do you think would be a better name? That's why i've named it `AsIEnumerable` in the first place, it doesn't really convert it to anything. It's convenient  if you need to add static objects to existing sequences or queries.

Comment: Perhaps `AsSequenceElement` or `Enumerable.FromElement` (no extension method). Personally I just go with `new[]{element}`. For the OP's use `ConcatSingle` is nicest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method for converting a single value to an IEnumerable

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToIEnumerable<T>(this T singleItem)
    {
        yield return singleItem;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
Enumerable.Repeat(100, 100).Concat(3.ToIEnumerable())
```