# Depth-first flattened collection of an object hierarchy using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, hierarchy, depth-first-search, flatten

I have an object hierarchy (MasterNode -> ChildNodes) where master and child nodes are of the same type, and there are only two levels (top level and children) like this ('A' is parent of D,E and F, 'B' is parent of G, etc)

```
A--+
|  D
|  E
|  F
|
B--+
|  G
|
C--+
   H
   I
```

Suppose I have a **MasterNodes** as an IEnumerable of the parent objects (A,B,C) and given a parent object **X** I can get an IEnumerable of its children by **X.children**

I know that I can enumerate all of the leaf (child nodes) with the **SelectMany** method or by using

```
from parent in Masternodes
from child in parent.children
select child
```

This will give me this sequence:

```
[D,E,F,G,H,I]
```

,but this is not what I am asking for.

**What is the LINQ query to get a depth-first sequence of the objects in the MasterNodes collection?** (return first parent then all of its children then next parent then all of its children etc etc)

The expected result should be a sequence like this:

```
[A,D,E,F,B,G,C,H,I]
```

**UPDATE**:

I am asking for pure .NET ready LINQ. I know that I can define my own methods to do things, but I want something that is based only on the framework provided methods.

Comment: LINQ can help to write understandable code but it does not contain a EnumerateDepthFirstTwoLevelDeep method. You need to compose several LINQ methods to get the desired result. If such a method would exist it would take longer to find it than to write the few lines at once because the LINQ designers would need to provide many hundreds if not thousands of additional methods to match your specific case and many different ones as well.

Comment: That is what I was asking for. Those two lines for this specific case :) Heinzi's answer is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need more than two hierarchy levels you can use the following extension method which goes recursively through your object graph:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> l, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> f) =>
        l.SelectMany(i => new T[] { i }.Concat(f(i).Flat(f)));
```

It flattens the given `IEnumerable<T>` with the use of a function that maps a `T` to an `IEnumerable<T>` describing the parent -> children relation of your data.

The depth-first flattening is done by concatinating every element with its sub-tree and then joining them with `SelectMany`.

You can use it like this:

```
var flattened = Masternodes.Flat(c => c.children);
```

Comment: ΙI like this answer because it is more generic.

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to this answer if you think it is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a class like below

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}
```

your linq would be

```
 Func<IEnumerable<Node>, IEnumerable<Node>> Flatten = null;
 Flatten = coll => coll.SelectMany(n=>n.Concat(Flatten(n.Children)));
```

Test Code:

```
Node[] roots = new Node[]{ new Node(){Name="A"},new Node(){Name="B"},new Node(){Name="C"} };
roots[0].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="D"});
roots[0].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="E"});
roots[0].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="F"});

roots[1].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="G"});

roots[2].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="H"});
roots[2].Children.Add(new Node(){Name="I"});

Func<IEnumerable<Node>, IEnumerable<Node>> Flatten = null;
Flatten = coll => coll.SelectMany(n=>n.Concat(Flatten(n.Children)));

var result = String.Join(",",Flatten(roots).Select(x=>x.Name));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I know recursive lamba is not very readible but it is 2 lines of code in the end.

Comment: You could also use a third party graph library like http://nuget.org/packages/QuickGraph which include depth first recursion.

Comment: @L.B: Personally, I would have made it a regular recursive method as it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have only two levels, the following approach should work:

```
var result = (from parent in masternodes
              select new Node[] { parent }.Concat(parent.children)).SelectMany(i => i);
```

First, it creates enumerables of the parent plus its children:

```
[A, D, E, F]
[B, G]
[C, H]
```

and then it flattens them with `SelectMany`.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what came to my mind shortly after I posted the question. Is there a LINQ method to convert an Object x into an IEnumerable that contains this object? Or I have to use the new Node[]{...} way?

Comment: Although it's not the only reply that answers the question, I picked it because it is short, quick, clean and right into the spot

Comment: @Saysmaster: There's nothing *really* elegant for creating a single-item IEnumerable. Another option would be `Enumerable.Repat(item, 1)` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019737/favorite-way-to-create-an-new-ienumerablet-sequence-from-a-single-value)) or creating an extension method for this purpose (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577822/passing-a-single-item-as-ienumerablet)).

Answer (score 0):

Say, we have the following classes:

```
public class MasterNode : ChildNode
{
    public List<ChildNode> ChildNodes;
}

public class ChildNode
{
    public string Value;
}
```

then

```
        List<MasterNode> list = new List<MasterNode>
        {
            new MasterNode
            {
                Value="A", 
                ChildNodes = new List<ChildNode>
                {
                    new ChildNode{Value = "D"},
                    new ChildNode{Value = "E"},
                    new ChildNode{Value = "F"}
                }
            },
            new MasterNode
            {
                Value="B", 
                ChildNodes = new List<ChildNode>
                {                        
                    new ChildNode{Value = "G"}
                }
            },
            new MasterNode
            {
                Value="C", 
                ChildNodes = new List<ChildNode>
                {
                    new ChildNode{Value = "H"},
                    new ChildNode{Value = "I"}
                }
            }
        };

        foreach (ChildNode c in list.SelectMany(l =>
                                {
                                   List<ChildNode> result = l.ChildNodes.ToList();
                                   result.Insert(0, l);
                                   return result;
                                }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
        }
```