# Recursively get all nodes that match in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

Is there a way to do the following in linq?

```
//item properties
//EntityId
//ParentEntityId
//HierarchyLevel

var topItem = myList.Single(x => x.HierarchyLevel == 0);
var level1 = myList.Where(x => x.ParentEntityId == topItem.EntityId);

//can i do the next step in LINQ?
//var level2 =
```

What about level 3?  is I've done this in SQL with CTEs but not sure the right way to do it in C#.

Comment: Linq isn't really suited for recursion.

Comment: Yes  you can use linq for recursion, but to get an answer, you have to post a better question. See for ex this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243888/932418

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1) Query for the next level using info from the previous one. So basically using recursion, but not doing everything in one step in LINQ.

```
var currLevel = myList.Where(x => x.HierarchyLevel == 0);
while (currLevel.Any())
{
    // Note: Maybe faster if myList was converted to a lookup first
    //       for this part, but this won't be an option if this is
    //       Linq2Sql, EF, etc. unless you pull everything into memory.
    var nextLevel = myList.Where(x => currLevel.Select(c => c.EntityId)
                                               .Contains(x.ParentEntityId));

    // Do something here with additional levels.

    var currLevel = nextLevel;
}
```

2) Use something like LINQ [AsHierarchy](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18#AsHierarchy), which essentially does the same, but presents it in a reusable data structure:

```
var root = myList.AsHierarchy(x => x.EntityId, x => x.ParentEntityId)
                 .Single();

var level2 = root.ChildNodes;

var level3 = level2.SelectMany(x => x.ChildNodes);
```

3) Write it as a SQL Function/Stored Proc that has a CTE, then map it to your EF context (assuming you're using EF since you mentioned SQL).

---

If you're looking for something like LINQ that will convert to a recursive SQL call, there is no such solution. The best you'll get is pulling all the data into memory and doing recursion there, or executing a query once per level.

Comment: the technologically arcane business I work with thinks entity framework is bad and would rather re-solve that problem with custom code